# CSV to JSON script

Tags: python, json, csv

I took this script from [here](http://www.johntron.com/creations/csv-to-json/):

```
import csv
from itertools import izip
f = open( '/django/sw2/wkw2/csvtest1.csv', 'r' )
reader = csv.reader( f )
keys = ( "firm_url", "firm_name", "first", "last", "school", "year_graduated" )
out = []
for property in reader:
    property = iter( property )
    data = {}
    for key in keys:
        data[ key ] = property.next()
    out += [ data ]
print out
```

When I tried it in IDLE I got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 5, in <module>
    data [key] = property.next()
StopIteration
```

But I tried

```
print out
```

again and then it printed

```
[{'school': 'The George Washington University Law School', 'last': 'Abbas', 'firm_url': 'http://www.whitecase.com/aabbas', 'year_graduated': ' 2005', 'firm_name': 'White & Case', 'first': ' Amr A '}, {'school': 'Ernst Moritz Arndt University Greifswald', 'last': 'Adam', 'firm_url': 'http://www.whitecase.com/kadam', 'year_graduated': ' 2004', 'firm_name': 'White & Case', 'first': ' Karin '}, {'school': 'Tashkent State Law Institute', 'last': 'Adjivefayev', 'firm_url': 'http://www.whitecase.com/vadjivefayev', 'year_graduated': ' 2002', 'firm_name': 'White & Case', 'first': ' Vilen '}]
```

But when I try to run it as a script, it doesn't work, I get the same error message.

Can anyone help fix the error?

(And is it outputting valid json?)

Thanks

**Edit**

Thanks for the answers. It seems that this is not the right way of converting a csv file to json format. I am just trying to convert the csv file with data in it so that I can use `loaddata` to populate my sqlite3 database in django. See this thread in django group: http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_frm/thread/a00b529ba2147d91 for my attempt to use csv2json.py snippet. And another thread today in OS (Sorry I cannot include 2 links). I would appreciate a simple way of converting csv to json. Or the method you use to populate your django database that I should be using instead. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The other OS thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882469/how-do-i-transfer-data-in-csv-file-into-my-sqlite-database-in-django/1882533#1882533

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change the nested `for` loop to:

```
out = [dict(zip(keys, property)) for property in reader]
```

and, no, `print out` will not emit valid JSON -- use `print json.dumps(out)` (you'll need to `import json` too of course -- that's a Python 2.6 standard library module but you can find versions working with 2.5 if that's what you need).

Comment: Thanks! This works. But I couldn't use loaddata with that file. I'll ask that separately after I try a few more things.

Comment: +1 That's a nice piece of code. I'll be steal^h^h^h^h^h using this idea really soon.

Answer (score 3):

With the [CSV Module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) you already have a [dict reader](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) built in! Here's an example script which can be used as a command line tool:

```
import csv
import json

def csvToJson( inFile, outFile ):
    out = None;

    with open( inFile, 'r') as csvFile:
        #Note this reads the first line as the keys we can add specific keys with:
        #csv.DictReader( csvFile, fieldnames=<LIST HERE>, restkey=None, restval=None, )
        csvDict = csv.DictReader( csvFile, restkey=None, restval=None, )
        out = [obj for obj in csvDict]

    if out:
        with open( outFile, 'w' ) as jsonFile:
            jsonFile.write( json.dumps( out ) );
    else:
       print "Error creating csv dict!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
     import argparse

     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
     parser.add_argument('inFile', nargs=1, help="Choose the in file to use")
     parser.add_argument('outFile', nargs=1, help="Choose the out file to use")
     args = parser.parse_args()
     csvToJson( args.inFile[0] , args.outFile[0] );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv
import json
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
keys = next(reader) #skip the headers  
out = [{key: val for key, val in zip(keys, prop)} for prop in reader]
json.dumps(out)
```

Comment: I really like your solution...just for new in python should be better if you explain that f is:

f = open('/path/file', 'r')

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to parse an empty line at the end of the file

```
for property in reader:
    print repr(property)         # <---try adding a print here
    property = iter( property )
```

Also csv.DictReader may do what you want already

```
csv.DictReader(f,fields=("firm_url", "firm_name", "first", "last", "school", "year_graduated" ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not actually creating JSON, I'm not sure about the last question.  You're just printing a Python dictionary.  They're mostly JSON, but not always.

So you should find a good `json` module and use that.  If you have Python 2.6: http://docs.python.org/library/json.html

Also, `csv` has a dictionary reader that does all of this in a much shorter and easier to live with form.  http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

---

Edit.

```
import csv
from your.app.models import YourClass

with open( "path/to/your/file.csv", "rb" ) as src:
    rdr = csv.DictReader( src )
    for row in rdr:
        x= YourClass.objects.create( field=row['column'], field=row['column'], ... )
        x.save()
        print x
```

Something like that usually works better.